# Why is this Binding not working in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm using this XAML to simulate watermark text on a textbox, but the binding for the Text Property is not working:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtSearch" BorderThickness="0">
  <ap:CueBannerService.CueBanner>
    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Opacity=".7" Text="{Binding Path=WatermarkText}"/>
  </ap:CueBannerService.CueBanner>
</TextBox>
```

On the other hand, any of the follow code works:

```
<TextBlock Foreground="Black" Opacity=".7" Text="Watermark Test"/>
<TextBox Opacity=".7" Text="{Binding Path=WatermarkText}"/>
```

Why is not working? thank you!

**UPDATE**

This also works fine (without the TextBlock):

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtSearch" BorderThickness="0" ap:CueBannerService.CueBanner="{Binding Path=WatermarkText}">
```

**UPDATE 2**

This Also works!:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtSearch" BorderThickness="0">
  <ap:CueBannerService.CueBanner>
    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Opacity=".7" Text="Watermark Text"/>
  </ap:CueBannerService.CueBanner>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the binding that isn't working? What happens if you put static text there? Do you see it?

Comment: Clearly your binding is working.  You show that it works.  It's that `CueBannerService` that's probably not working...

Comment: Hi. Yes the binding is working. As you see in the second example it works fine with a textbox text property. If i use static text it works. I suspect i need to change the binding to work inside CueBannerService.

Comment: What's ap:CueBannerService.CueBanner? If it's not a part of the visual tree, then it won't inherit the DataContext, causing the binding to not work.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the binding for TextBlock with the following:

{Binding DataContext.WatermarkText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}}

Will check why this did not work.

---

This should work! We are ensuring that the DataContext that is assosciated with the TextBox is being used for the TextBlock:

{Binding DataContext.WatermarkText, ElementName=txtSearch}

Comment: Thanks for the answer but didn't work. I get this error: Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.TextBox', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.WatermarkText; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

Comment: Eric, please check with the updated binidng that I posted above. thanks

Comment: I would guess that the `CueBannerService` service is not attaching the `CueBanner` property value to either the logical or visual tree of the target element, and therefore the value is not inheriting the data context of the target element. This would also prevent bindings within the value element from referencing the target via `ElementName` (as it is not in the same name scope), or resolving it via `AncestorType` (as it is not in the same visual tree).